# Image Sequence Shows Last Frame Past When Sequence Ends

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am compositing a smoke effect that didn't render (I had forgotten to include the smoke cache on the computer I was using to render). The whole sequence is 400 frames, I only need the smoke to run to 291 (the end of the sequence) after which I included the smoke in the original render.

To composite using Blenders compositor, I have the image sequence in the compositor and my fix works perfectly - except that after the end of the smoke sequence the last image of the smoke image sequence lingers on in the render - it should be blank.

[image: Last frame of smoke showing]

The smoke "fix" ends at frame 291, and my screen grab is from 364 so you can clearly see that frame 291 is showing in the composite. There MUST be a simple way of fixing this. otherwise how would one put a simple overlay into the composite when necessary? I guess One solution would be to make a completely blank frame at 292 for that sequence.

Comment: Sure, if you don't want any overlay after frame 291, just don't overlay it anymore...? I don't understand what's the problem here. And as the question reads, it sounds as if the original render is okay after 291, so why re-render anything past 291 anyway? Either it is a bit misunderstandable what the issue is, or there is no real issue...?

Comment: I wondered if this would be a hard problem to communicate...the problem is, the final frame of overlay (the smoke) shows past its final frame. Instead of the image disappearing is it would in other compositors, it carries on. So frame 291 of that overlay is showing in frames 292, 293, 294 and so on. You can see the effect of this in the image above.

Comment: Yes, I understood that it's showing on the other frames. My question is, you make it overlay the other frames. Why don't you just stop overlaying it after frame 291? Please clarify how you have set it up that it seems impossible to you to simply not overlay it anymore?

Comment: Well how do you do that? If you add an image sequence node in the compositor, and the sequence overlays until 291, the last frame continues to be displayed. I guess one way would be to render out from the compositor to 291, mute the image sequence node and then continue rendering. Or, in the end I made a blank alpha image at 292 for that sequence. These are workarounds though. How do you make it not overlay when you get to 292?

Comment: The compositor is not a sequencer. Every image texture/sequence node if not muted or set to a factor 0 if mixed in with a color mix node will output something - and if there is nothing else to display after frame 291 it will show the last frame. Like image texture nodes elsewhere, for example the shader editor, if you load an image, it cannot "not" output the image, you have to mute it or change the mix. If you want a sequence to only last for a certain frame range without muting, use the Video Sequence Editor. There an image sequence strip will only show until the strip ends.